# unable to invoke tha getLocationweatherdetails(latitude,longitude) from ananymous class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-maps-v2

```
/**
 * A function to request the current location. Using the fused location provider client.
 */
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun requestLocationData() {

    val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
    mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    mLocationRequest.interval = 1000
    mLocationRequest.numUpdates = 1

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
        mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
        Looper.myLooper()!!)

   // getLocationWeatherDetails(34.00,55.00)
}

/**
 * A location callback object of fused location provider client where we will
 * get the current location details.
 */
private val mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
    override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
        val mLastLocation: Location = locationResult.lastLocation
        val latitude = mLastLocation.latitude
        Log.i("Current_Latitude", "$latitude")

        val longitude = mLastLocation.longitude
        Log.i("Current_Longitude", "$longitude")

        //getLocationWeatherDetails(latitude, longitude)
        getLocationWeatherDetails(latitude,longitude)
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem is i have a function getLocationWeatherDetails(latitude:Double, longitude:Double) but the  getLocationWeatherDetails is not called and i cannot see the latitude and longitude value in logcat